# CasperJS tests fail from some machines, succeed on others

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

Having a strange problem where certain CasperJS tests fail on some machines (all different versions of OS X) and not others, even though the version of CasperJS, PhantomJS, Node and NPM are all the same. What am I missing? Simplified version of the code follows:

```
var userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0',
    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=apple&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8',
    selector = '#tads.c',
    timeoutMs = 10000;

casper.test.begin("test1", 1, function(test) {    
        casper.userAgent(userAgent);    
        casper.start(url)
        .waitForSelector(selector, function() {    
                test.assertExists(selector, 'selector: ' + selector);    
            }, function timeout() {    
                test.fail(selector + ' timed out after ' + timeoutMs + ' ms');    
            }, timeoutMs)    
        .run(function() {    
                test.done();
            });
    });
```

Comment: 1. Check `require(''utils).dump(phantom.version)` if the PhantomJS version is actually the same. 2. Maybe it is network related. Are either of those machines (works/doesn't) on the same network?

Comment: same (wifi) network and same phantom.version

Comment: Is it possible that the test works as expected, and the fail is caused by a different search results?
As a quick check, i've opened link you test in browser - https://www.google.com/search?q=apple&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 - it showed no ads block for me - **document.querySelector('#tads.c')** returns **null** and the test would fail in that case.
Try saving a screenshot on fail, that way you could see what happens on the page when the test fails 
http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#capture

Comment: Yes, we've tried this. In the cases where the tests fail (which is always the same set of machines, even on different networks) we get a blank screenshot. On the machines that pass, we get the expected screenshot - same as when visiting via the browser.

Comment: Also, this is not an intermittent problem -- a given test machine gives the same result every time, whether failing or passing.

Comment: And the selector is there when visited in the browser, on both sets of machines.